# Attempt to test Person class, unsuccessful.

Tags: java

Okay, so I'm supposed to be creating the Person class with fields for holding a persons name, address and phone # which will later be extended by a Customer class.

```
    public class Person
{
   //Instance Variables
   private String name;
   private String street;
   private String cityStateZip;
   private String phone;

   //Constructors
   public Person()
   {
      String name = "";
      String street = "";
      String cityStateZip = "";
      String phone = "";
   }
   public Person(String name, String street, String cityStateZip,
                  String phone)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.street = street;
      this.cityStateZip = cityStateZip;
      this.phone = phone;
   }
   public Person(Person person)
   {
      new Person();
   }

   //Mutators
   public void setName(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public void setStreet(String street)
   {
      this.street = street;
   }
   public void setCityStateZip(String cityStateZip)
   {
      this.cityStateZip = cityStateZip;
   }
   public void setPhone(String phone)
   {
      this.phone = phone;
   }

   //Accessors
   public String getName()
   {

   return name;
   }
   public String getStreet()
   {

   return street;
   }
   public String getCityStateZip()
   {

   return cityStateZip;
   }
   public String getPhone()
   {

   return phone;
   }
   public String toString()
   {

   return name + "/n" + street + "/n" + cityStateZip + "/n" + phone;
   }    
}
```

okay, so...I changed a bit of my code up, fixed my dang private/public errors... i'm forever getting the +/- mixed up.... this file compiles now. I'm trying to create a class to test it and i'm running into a few problems with that. here's the errors im getting at the moment

----jGRASP exec: javac -g TestPerson.java

```
TestPerson.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
      name = keyboard.nextLine;
                     ^
  symbol:   variable nextLine
  location: variable keyboard of type Scanner
TestPerson.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
      street = keyboard.nextLine;
                       ^
  symbol:   variable nextLine
  location: variable keyboard of type Scanner
TestPerson.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
      cityStateZip = keyboard.nextLine;
                             ^
  symbol:   variable nextLine
  location: variable keyboard of type Scanner
TestPerson.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
      phone = keyboard.nextLine;
                      ^
  symbol:   variable nextLine
  location: variable keyboard of type Scanner
TestPerson.java:38: error: non-static method getName() cannot be referenced from a static context
      getName()+ "\n" + getStreet() + "\n" + getCityStateZip() + "\n" 
      ^
TestPerson.java:38: error: non-static method getStreet() cannot be referenced from a static context
      getName()+ "\n" + getStreet() + "\n" + getCityStateZip() + "\n" 
                        ^
TestPerson.java:38: error: non-static method getCityStateZip() cannot be referenced from a static context
      getName()+ "\n" + getStreet() + "\n" + getCityStateZip() + "\n" 
                                             ^
TestPerson.java:39: error: non-static method getPhone() cannot be referenced from a static context
      + getPhone());
        ^
8 errors



 import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class TestPerson extends Person 
{


   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      String name;
      System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
      name = keyboard.nextLine;

      String street;
      System.out.println("Enter your street: ");
      street = keyboard.nextLine;

      String cityStateZip;
      System.out.println("Enter your city, state and zip code: ");
      cityStateZip = keyboard.nextLine;

      String phone;   
      System.out.println("Enter your phone number: ");
      phone = keyboard.nextLine;

      System.out.println("Tested person's information is as follows: " +
      getName()+ "\n" + getStreet() + "\n" + getCityStateZip() + "\n" 
      + getPhone());
      System.out.println(new Person());

      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why is *every* method private?!  Even the constructors!  That aside, when you're calling `toString` on a class, you want to put information about the current instance in that string.  You're creating a new String here.

Answer (score 4):

The exact error that you're getting is because you're taking what used to be a public method (`toString`) and making it a private method.

Your `Person` class is of type `Object` because all classes in Java inherit from `Object`. Anybody that gets passed an `Object` expects it to have a `toString` method that they can use. If `toString` is private, they can't do this and so Java complains.

On a side note, the code in your toString looks wrong too.

Answer (score 2):

```
private String toString()
```

you are overriding `Object's toString` method that too with more restrictive constraints than `public` which is not obeying the rules of `method overriding` in `java`.

it should be

```
public String toString()
```

Comment: The error message is clear and concise. attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public.

Answer (score 2):

```
If you want to access your person class and its details in other class 
you   should not make person class constructor as private .if so you 
can't    create a object of person class in other tester classes.  
try it as public.   

Private constructor can be used for **Static factory method()** inside
the class itself and also some utility based classes and also for static 
method(which is for no object creation).

      If you make toString() as private, for this a protected 
instance method in the superclass can be made public,  but not private, 
in the subclass.

This because inheritance creates an IS-A relation between two classes, 
for which the Liskov substitution principle must be valid. Without 
having the previous constraint that would be impossible to enforce.
```

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` needs to be public, because other methods (such as `println()`) need to access it.

In general, you need to think about what should be private and what should be public. You've made everything private, even when that doesn't make sense (constructors). Your getters and setters should be public as well; that's the point of getters and setters.